# Powering an Arduino with a Supercapacitor

Tags: arduino, capacitor, supercapacitor

For the purpose of a project I wish to power an arduino using a supercapacitor charged to 5V. The supercapacitor will be fed straight into the power Vin and GND terminals on the Arduino. No power plug or USB connected to a computer will be connected, so all power is to be drawn from the supercapacitor. Previously I have powered the board using a 0-12V variable voltage supply, and the arduino draws between 20 and 35 milliamps.

My question is this, if I connect the supercapacitor straight to the arduino board, will the arduino govern how much current to draw from the supercapacitor? Or will I need to place a resistor in series with the supercapacitor discharging in order to regulate current and stop the supercapacitor rapidly discharging and frying the board?

Lastly is this feasible at all? I am aware that as the 5V from the supercapacitor will drop off the period during which the arduino will run is limited.

Any advice is appreciated as I  do not wish to fry my Arduino board attempting this.

Comment: The arduino will draw the current it requires. It is certainly feasible, you will need to decide what run time you desire, and from that are able to work out how big the capacitor(s) need to be.

Comment: Perfect thanks Colin! The runtime will be quite short and I have a 15F supercapacitor so it should store enough charge. So you are saying I will need not need to add any resistor for discharging the supercapacitor?

Comment: Yes, current isn't 'pushed' into devices really. If it is designed to operate at 5 V and you attach it to a 5 V source it will draw the current from the source it needs.

Comment: You will get more run time if you use a 5V regulator and e.g. a 12V capacitor. Also beware of the in-rush current with a 15F capacitor!

Comment: I'm seconding oldfart's concern about inrush current. You might need to set up some combination of resistors & diodes to allow it to charge slowly but discharge without wasting power.

Comment: If i were to add a resistor for the purpose of limiting inrush current, say 50ohm, so the max current is now 5/50 = 100mA. The arduino has only been drawing 35mA maximum. So would there be any chance of this inrush resistor disrupting with the arduinos capability to draw current? I will also be adding a fuse in case of inrush, so that the board is protected should this occur

Comment: That's why "some combination of resistors and diodes."  You want current limiting when the cap is charging from a low-impedance power supply, but you don't want energy wasted when it is discharging.

Comment: Where did you get a 5 V supercapacitor?

Comment: Is there any reason other than "because it's there" why you want to do this? Supercapacitators excel at delivering high currents, but suck in every other respect compared to a cheap rechargeagble battery. An arduino doesn't precisely need lots of current, so... not sure this is a sensible approach at all?

Comment: The reason is basically 'because its there'. Its for a college project taking an existing setup and using just supercapacitors as a power source. An arduino is a part of the setup

Comment: @Damon Surely supercapacitors could also excel at ultrafast charging, such as being charged in a few seconds to then power a lower power Arduino for half an hour or so. Or would this put the Arduino at risk?

Answer (score 21):

The voltage on a capacitor is proportional to the charge stored in it.

That means that as the device draws current, the voltage will drop.  You have to decide how low is acceptable.  Do the math.

For example, let's say the device can still run from 4.5 V.  That means the capacitor voltage can drop 500 mV before the system doesn't work anymore.  Let's use a 1 F cap as example.

(500 mV)(1 F) / (35 mA) = 14.3 s

That's how long a 1 F cap charged to 5 V can run your device at the worst case current draw.

Comment: I would suggest a boost regulator such as LT3426, see page 9 for circuit examples for 5V <http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3426fb.pdf> and feed the output into the 5V pin, and not the Vin pin (Vin then goes thru a 5V regulator, you won't get 5V out).

Comment: A one farad cap would be the Godzilla of capacitors.

Comment: @Zeta: That used to be true a couple of decades ago, but not anymore.  Look up things called "super caps" and "ultra caps".

Answer (score 15):

First to answer your question (Although that has been done in the comments already):  No you do not need a resistor to limit the current. The Arduino will take just what it needs.

Next:
Your discharge over a small voltage range 5v down to 4.5V will be ~CV/I. Olin gave a figure for that.

**BUT!**
You can get a lot more time using a smaller and cheaper capacitor if you would use a 5 Volt regulator and e.g. a 12V capacitor. 
Let's say you want 10 seconds whilst the voltage drops from 5V to 4.5V. You need a capacitor of 0.035*10/0.5 = 0.7 Farad.

Some assumptions:
We use 12V, have 0.5V drop over the regulator and it uses an extra 1ma. 
The voltage can now drop 6.5 Volts (and we still have 5V on the Arduino).
You now need a capacitor of 0.036*10/6.5 = 0.055 Farad.
Yes, you need a higher voltage supercap but it can be much, much smaller.

Comment: Most Arduinos have a LDO regulator on board at the VIN pin, so the OP wouldn't even need additional components.

Comment: I have just read that the Vin pin regulates to 5v and so can take in a voltage from 5-12V. The capacitor I have has a max voltage of 7V, so I may charge to this max voltage for added runtime (7v down to probably 4.5v)

Comment: the LDO still has *some* drop-out voltage. so it'll probably drop out around 6V

Comment: @dn3s In my experience, the voltage drop from the LDO is negligible at the current draw from an Arduino, and it will work fine to less than 5V on VIN (the MCU can also tolerate quite a margin below 5V)

Comment: huh i didn't know that was a thing, I was under the impression that LDOs just shut down under the dropout voltage, are you saying they just derate current / drop below the regulated voltage? that's neat. i could see how that might go undocumented in datasheets which would explain me not knowing this

Answer (score 10):

Another option could be to get a DC-DC step up converter which gives a 5V output. This can run on an input of 0.9V - 5V.

Based on your 15F capacitor and a voltage drop of 4V (for a 5.5V supercapacitor charged to 5V) you could get 4000mV * 15F / 41mA (85% efficient) = 1,463s or about 24 minutes run time.

Comment: The 15F capacitor has a max voltage of 7V, so I had planned to charge to 5V

Comment: @TRJ94 - I've changed the calculation to use a supercapacitor charged to 5V instead of a 2.7V one. Ironically, I'd calculated both, and accidentally put the answer for the supercapacitor charged to 5V in.